# Update strings in a very large database

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I'm trying to update/replace few strings on MYSQL/MARIADB database, all I need is:

Change all this exact strings `http://mysite.app` for `https://mysite.app` in ALL the database

The problem is that this database is VERY LARGE and a normal replace could break the server.

So I would like to know how do this per cicles or time or something that don't affect too much the server ¿is it possible?

Comment: change in all tables or in all databases and all tables ?

Comment: Also define _very large_

Comment: It's just 1 database, to change all 'http://mysite.app' that found on entire database (all tables). 11GB

Comment: You don't want it to run continuously, correct? Maybe using `LIMIT` and cycle it?

Comment: Exactly! This is what I need. Do the job but per cycles/limit (will be slower but safer for server loads). Do you know how could be that rule on SQL?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a query like this to generate all queries to do that:
if you remove **GROUP_CONCAT(** and **SEPARATOR '\n' )** you will get one row per update statemant.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(
    CONCAT('UPDATE `',TABLE_SCHEMA,'`.`',TABLE_NAME,'` SET `',
        COLUMN_NAME,'` = REPLACE(',COLUMN_NAME,',\'http://mydomain\',\'https://mydomain\');')
        SEPARATOR '\n' ) as myquery
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS`
WHERE
    `TABLE_SCHEMA` not IN ('information_schema','performance_schema','mysql') -- excluded SCHEMAS
AND
    `DATA_TYPE` in ('varchar','char');
```

**sample**

```
    UPDATE `shopware`.`s_core_log` SET `value4` = REPLACE(value4,'http://mydomain','https://mydomain');
    UPDATE `shopware`.`s_core_engine_groups` SET `name` = REPLACE(name,'http://mydomain','https://mydomain');
    UPDATE `shopware`.`s_core_engine_groups` SET `label` = REPLACE(label,'http://mydomain','https://mydomain');
    UPDATE `shopware`.`s_core_engine_groups` SET `layout` = REPLACE(layout,'http://mydomain','https://mydomain');
    UPDATE `shopware`.`s_core_subscribes` SET `subscribe` = REPLACE(subscribe,'http://mydomain','https://mydomain');
....

    UPDATE `shopware`.`s_order_billingaddress` SET `additional_address_line1` = REPLACE(additional_address_line1,'http://mydomain','https://mydomain');
    UPDATE `shopware`.`s_order_billingaddress` SET `additional_address_line2` = REPLACE(additional_address_line2,'http://mydomain','https://mydomain');
    UPDATE `shopware`.`s_order_billingaddress` SET `title` = REPLACE(title,'http://mydomain','https://mydomain');
```